# Cannot Send Class Object From One Scene to Another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I’m developing a Unity game.
I have a login scene in the game that fetches user information from the database.
After fetching the user information, a model class which is named as RegisteredUser is used to hold the user credentials.
I need to send the created RegisteredUser class object to the next scene. But I cannot send it directly. When I try it, I get NullExceptionError and the object is lost. How can I fix it?
This is the callback function that user credentials are returned:

```
   public void userInfo (RegisteredUser newUser)
{
    loggedinUser.FirstName = newUser.FirstName;
    loggedinUser.LastName = newUser.LastName;
    loggedinUser.Email = newUser.Email;
    loggedinUser.Gender = newUser.Gender;


}
```

And this is the part where I want to fetch the name and surname of the user to print on the text field:

```
 void Start()
{
  //  string userName = currentUser.FirstName + currentUser.LastName;
    welcomeText = GameObject.Find("Canvas/SidebarPanel/WelcomeText").GetComponent<Text>();

}
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Comment: But as far as I know, DontDestroyOnLoad is used for game objects that belong to the scene. But the class object that I want to pass is not a game object. Is it still possible to pass it? @RetiredNinja

Comment: This question isn't about [tag:unityscript], it is about [tag:c#]

Comment: Use a `ScriptableObject`. They're designed to persist project-global data between scene transitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your object in a field/property of a MonoBehaviour script that is marked DontDestroyOnLoad.

This object will persist and so will its data.

```
public class PersistentDataContainer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RegisteredUser UserInfo;

    private void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}
```